# Pandas to_datetime doesn't work as hoped with format %d.%m.%Y

Tags: python, pandas, date, sorting

I have a pandas dataframe with a text column containing strings in the format:

```
28.08.1958
29.04.1958
01.02.1958
05.03.1958
```

that I want to interpret as dates. The dataframe arises from using beautifulsoup, i.e. I've not read it in from csv, so I planned to use pd.to_datetime().  There are occasional non-date entries so I added the errors='ignore'.

```
df["Date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%d.%m.%Y', errors='ignore')
```

It looks to me as if this isn't working as I have used a subsequent sort operation:

```
df.sort_values(by="Date2", ascending=True)
```

and this does change the order but seemingly randomly, not into date order.
I wondered if there might be whitespace amongst the dates so as a precaution I used:

```
['Date'].str.strip()
```

but no improvement.

I also tried adding:

```
inplace=True
```

to the sort values but this results in the whole column being sorted by the days part of the date, which is really telling me that there is no conversion to date going on.

**In summary** I presume that all the input strings are being treated as errors and ignored. Perhaps this means that the parameter format='%d.%m.%Y' isn't right.

**EDIT** In response to the comments/answer so far I've found a way of inducing an input dataset that has no errors in it. This seems to sort ok. What's more I can see that the data type of the "Date2" column depends upon whether there are errors in that column: if there is non-date text then the column is of type object, if no errors it is datetime64[ns]

**Solution**  I've set
errors='coerce'
within the to_datetime statement.

Comment: Please post df.dtypes -= after the to_datetime command

Comment: @gtomer thanks but I don't know what you are referring to. I've looked up df.dtypes but can't see how I'm supposed to use it with to_datetime

Comment: @gtomer ah ha, the penny has dropped, I thought you wanted me to make some compound statement.

Comment: The outcome is that the "Date2" column is of type object

Comment: Did you get an answer,  i have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''                  
Date
28.08.1958
29.04.1958
01.02.1958
05.03.1958
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))
df["Date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%d.%m.%Y')
df.sort_values(by="Date2", ascending=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

---

```
         Date      Date2
2  01.02.1958 1958-02-01
3  05.03.1958 1958-03-05
1  29.04.1958 1958-04-29
0  28.08.1958 1958-08-28
```

Comment: I can see this works as it is. i.e. it seems to imply that format='%d.%m.%Y' is ok. I tried it with errors='ignore' and there was no further problem, i.e. still ok. I then added a broken date and a non-date line of text and it still handled it ok.  I don't get what could be wrong with my code whilst yours is fine. Does the read_csv(io.StringIO() do anything significant here? (mine isn't csv sourced data)

Comment: @Puffin, You need to check step by step. First after this line in your code : `df["Date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%d.%m.%Y', errors='ignore')` check this : `print(df["Date2"].dtype) -> Output should be : datetime64[ns]`. With this, We can check the converted input data from CSV to DateTime is working correctly or not.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it, see the EDIT at the foot of the question

Comment: @Puffin, You're welcome, have a good time ;)